# Not able to create relationships on huge data with Neo4j shell

Tags: neo4j

I've data about 20 million rows. The shell is going to infinite execution mode when firing create relationship queries. Is there any better approach to handle large data?

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing from CSV, you can use add [USING PERIODIC COMMIT](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-periodic-commit) to your import. This is supposed to allow import in the area of millions of records per second. This should prevent memory from being eaten up as it batches the import for you.

Comment: I'm able to import data. I'm facing issues with creating relationships. Does it work in this case as well?

Comment: There are tools to help (see [apoc.periodic.commit()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_job_management_and_periodic_execution) in the APOC Procedures library), but the first step should be to look at your Cypher for relationship creation. Can you add that to your description?